# Sendmail 8.15 is not rewriting sender domain

Tags: sendmail, masquerade

Sendmail 8.15 on a RHEL 8 system.
I am able to send mail out, but when I receive it on the other end, the 'from' address is user@FQDN instead of user@MASQUARADE_AS

**what we get: user@realhosname.realdomain.com**

**what we want: user@somedomain.com.au**

sendmail.mc config contains these among other macros:

```
MASQUERADE_AS(`somedomain.com.au')dnl
LOCAL_DOMAIN(`localhost.localdomain')dnl
EXPOSED_USER(`root')dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(somedomain.com.au)dnl
```

we do want the root user exposed as from the FQDN for management reasons, but we want all other users to show as user@MASQUERADE_AS

Testing the configuration, thing appear as they ought:

```
> =SHdrFromL
R< @ >          MAILER-DAEMON
R@ < @ $* >             MAILER-DAEMON
R$+             $: $> AddDomain $1
R$*             $: $> MasqHdr $1
> /tryflags HS
> /try local user
Trying header sender address user for mailer local
canonify           input: user
Canonify2          input: user
Canonify2        returns: user
canonify         returns: user
1                  input: user
1                returns: user
HdrFromL           input: user
AddDomain          input: user
AddDomain        returns: user < @ *LOCAL* >
MasqHdr            input: user < @ *LOCAL* >
MasqHdr          returns: user < @ somedomain . com . au . >
HdrFromL         returns: user < @ somedomain . com . au . >
final              input: user < @ somedomain . com . au . >
final            returns: user @ somedomain . com . au
Rcode = 0, addr = user@somedomain.com.au
> /try esmtp user
Trying header sender address user for mailer esmtp
canonify           input: user
Canonify2          input: user
Canonify2        returns: user
canonify         returns: user
1                  input: user
1                returns: user
HdrFromSMTP        input: user
PseudoToReal       input: user
PseudoToReal     returns: user
MasqSMTP           input: user
MasqSMTP         returns: user < @ *LOCAL* >
MasqHdr            input: user < @ *LOCAL* >
MasqHdr          returns: user < @ somedomain . com . au . >
HdrFromSMTP      returns: user < @ somedomain . com . au . >
final              input: user < @ somedomain . com . au . >
final            returns: user @ somedomain . com . au
Rcode = 0, addr = user@somedomain.com.au
>
```

Scratching my head, here. Are the other config directives I need to be looking at?

And, yes, I did run 'make' after editing the sendmail.mc file. :)

somedomain.com.au is an MX for the externally visible exit point for our mail (spf records, etc.).

============================

**FIX:**

So...we finally resolved it this way:

**sendmail.mc:**

```
FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl
MASQUERADE_AS(`somedomain.com.au')dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost.localdomain)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(`otherdomain.com')dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(`somehost.otherdoamin.com')dnl
```

**submit.mc:**

```
dnl define(`confDIRECT_SUBMISSION_MODIFIERS',`C')dnl
```

then recompiled and restarted and now we get the desired behavior: external users see our mail as coming from somdomain.com.au

Comment: Is `somedomain.com.au` server by `CNAME` DNS record?

Comment: Yes, the 'somedomain.com.au' is an alias (CNAM) for the domain. the actual domain can not be used, as that would force us to change hundreds of customer configurations.